# Select field based on previous select

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to populate a select dropdown from a previous select field (on the same page)

The first select, shows table names from a MYSQL db.
The second select should show column names from the selected table

Here is my code

**page.php**

```
<label class="">Select a Database Table</label>
 <select class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select Table" data-init-plugin="select2" onchange="showColumn(this.value);">
  <optgroup label="Table">

<?php

   $table_count = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'cl49-vclients'"); 

    $tables = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count))
    { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row["TABLE_NAME"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["TABLE_NAME"]; ?></option>
<?php
   }
?>
 <!-- </optgroup>-->
</select>
<script>
function showColumn(tablename)
{
    if(tablename !='')
    {
        $.ajax({ 
            type:"POST",
            url :"ajax.php"; 
            data:{tablename:tablename},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data); //This will alert column name comma separated  
            }       
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
//make database connection
$column_count = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM '".$_POST['tablename']."'"); 
    $columns = array();
    while($columnRow = mysql_fetch_array($column_count))
    {
        $columns[] = $columnRow['Field'];
    }   
    echo implode(',',$columns); //This will return column name comma separated 
?>

<label class="">Table</label>
  <select class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select Table" data-init-plugin="select2" onchange="showColumn(this.value);">
  <optgroup label="Table">

<?php
$table_count = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'cl49-vclients'"); 

    $tables = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count))
    {
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row["TABLE_NAME"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["TABLE_NAME"]; ?></option>
<?php
   }
?>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

The first select seems to be showing the table names fine, however when I select one another select field should appear but it doesnt, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked if your Ajax request is actually called? If so, what is the response? Have you checked any mysql errors?
And, of course: You should not use mysql functions. they are deprecated. Use mysqli or pdo instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second query you are not selecting any database. You need

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"information_schema");

SHOW COLUMNS FROM '".$_POST['tablename']."'
```

Alternatively, Replace your 2nd query like this

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'cl49-vclients' AND TABLE_NAME = '".$_POST['tablename']."';
```

Comment: Is this not coming from the first select field?

Comment: No. Your first query is generic but the second query is specific to a single database

Comment: Try the alternative query updated in answer. Execute that in phpmyadmin or mysql prompt hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax.php should only return the column names in CSV or the HTML for dropdown options, can't understand why it also contains the HTML for table names dropdown. And the `showColumn()` should place the returned data to the current page's HTML.

Your **page.php** JS function should be:

```
function showColumn(tablename)
{
    if(tablename !='')
    {
        $.ajax({ 
            type:"POST",
            url :"ajax.php"; 
            data:{tablename:tablename},
            success:function(data){
                $('#selColumns').html(data); // Assign the HTML returned by ajax.php to the second dropdown
            }       
        });
    }
}
```

and should also have following HTML for the second dropdown for columns:

```
<select id="selColumns" data-placeholder="Select Column">
</select>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
    //make database connection
    $column_count = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM '".$_POST['tablename']."'"); 
    while($columnRow = mysql_fetch_array($column_count))
        echo "<option value='" . $columnRow['Field'] . "'>" . $columnRow['Field'] . "</option>";
?>
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for this, On your answer, is that all that should be in ajax.php?

Comment: Yes, unless you run into some other issues. :)

Comment: I have done this, and th 2nd select shows, but is empty?

Comment: Any ideas on this one??

Comment: Is the ajax request successfull? what's the response from ajax.php?

Comment: You can get the error in the page's javascript console of the browser. You can also try adding `console.log(data);` in the `success` event handler, to get the `data` in the console.